# 18650 capacity tester opamp voltages on inputs different

Tags: arduino, voltage, operational-amplifier, diy, capacity

I assembled an 18650 Li-Ion capacity tester with an Arduino Pro Mini.
Here is the schematic:
[image]

When I set the discharging current to 100 mA in the code (which means there has to be 100mV on pin 3 of the opamp and there is), I'm measuring 300mV on pin 2 of the opamp!?

This absolutely does not make sense to me, as the opamp should strive to equalize the inputs.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone got an idea or experienced the same problem?

But it generally seems like the current value I set differs noticeably from the measured value.

E.g. when I set the discharging current to 500mA, I'm measuring like 600mA...

Anyone got an idea?

Edit: This is what the voltage on pin 1 of the opamp looks like. Referenced to GND. [image]

Comment: Broken op-amp maybe?

Comment: It's a new one from STM. 
I tried using the LMC6482 (it is pin compatible) but it seems like it fully switches the opamp and the current is more than 1 amp ...

Comment: What's the output voltage on pin 1 of the op-amp? Is it oscillating?

Comment: Seems like it's oscillating with ca. 30 kHz. I added an image of the voltage on pin 1 of the opamp

Comment: Not surprised, with only 1 Ohm to ground the op-amp is driving a high capacitive load. Try adding some resistance between the bottom of C5 and the top of R5.

Comment: I inserted a 1k resistor between bottom of C5 and top of R5 AND 
I added a 10uF capacitor between Gate and Source of the MOSFET and now it works perfectly! 

Comment: C5 should be only 500 pF (or a little less), and R4 10 Ohm.

Comment: Do you want PWM or analog signal ?

Comment: I want an analog signal, but since the Arduino does not have a DAC, but PWM, I put a low pass filter consisting of R3 and C4 before the OpAmp.